# VBA lookup then sum data based in cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write vba code that lookup the data shown in sheet2 in sheet1 and sum all similar values

[image]

I want to lookup value in A2 sheet2 in sheet1 and sum all duplicated value

Comment: Is there a real necessity of VBA? You can do this with a SUMIF formula instead. Have a look at the documentation https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b#:~:text=If%20you%20want%2C%20you%20can,%3AB5%20equal%20%22John.%22

Comment: thanks for trying to help but because its part of another codes also its variable data so need it to be dynamic